# Android Java: Diaglog setText & getText issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a dialog bux which opens when an textView is selected. The dialog box contains an editText. 
What i want to do is be able to type a sting into the editText, and when the 'Done' button is pressed it will store the string from the editText to a variable in which it can be viewed via the original textView.
My souce code is correct according to eclipse. however when i run it on my android phone, it crashes. I know that the reason for this is the OnClick Listner.

Below is my souce code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView showPopUpButton;//NEW
EditText getInput;//NEW

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showPopUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowPopUp);//NEW
    getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);//NEW

    showPopUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopUp3();              }
        });
}


private void showPopUp3() {
    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("Enter your string");

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View checkboxLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);
    helpBuilder.setView(checkboxLayout);

    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        TextView showPopUpButton;//NEW
        EditText getInput;//NEW
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // THIS IS SUPPOSED TO STORE THE VALUE OF THE EDIT-TEXT AND OUTPUT IT IN THE TEXTVIEW
                showPopUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowPopUp);//NEW
            showPopUpButton.setText(getInput.getText());//NEW**
            }
        });

    AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();
}
```

}

Thanks guys, i know this solution is possible easy, im just missing something small.
Thanks

Comment: the onClickListener is also to close the diaglog after the setText and getText processes are done.

Comment: is `showPopUpButton` really a `TextView` or is it a `Button`?

Comment: u are not initializing the local variable EditText getInput.. where u doing getInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextid); ..?? if its already in global u donot need declare again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your TextView is in main layout and EditText is in popuplayout.xml.
If this is the case then try following code. You can not get reference of EditText directly, you have to find it from it's layout(checkboxlayout).

```
private void showPopUp3() {
AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
helpBuilder.setTitle("Enter your string");

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View checkboxLayout =inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);
getInput = (EditText)  checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
getInput.setText(YOUR_STRING);
helpBuilder.setView(checkboxLayout);

helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // THIS IS SUPPOSED TO STORE THE VALUE OF THE EDIT-TEXT AND OUTPUT IT IN THE TEXTVIEW

        showPopUpButton.setText(getInput.getText());//NEW**
        }
    });

AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
helpDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks soo much,this worked for me. I just have a quick question. When i now press the done button it the string now shows. However when i open the dialog again, the string that i had entered clears, is there a way in which i could leave the string entered in the editText, to stay there?

Comment: your answer is perfect. +1 up.

Comment: I think i asked the question wrong. Basically i would like the contents of whats enter in the wditText to remain there, even when the done button is pressed.

Comment: store it in a string and everytime you show the popup set the edittext with the string, or set the edittext text from the textview text. The reason it doesn't stay is because the whole dialog gets destroyed when you close it

Comment: I've tried to add getInput.setText(YOUR_STRING); as shown above, however what exactly do i replace the 'YOUR_STRING' with as it will be dependant on what the user enters

Comment: Really? did you read the above comment? use the textview text

Comment: I'm sorry im abot confused, could you show me with the code example please. Thanks . . . Ive put getInput.setText(ShowPopUpButton);  which is the textview but theres an error

Comment: try like this `getInput.setText(ShowPopUpButton.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. If it doesn't you need to look in your logcat and post what it says when it crashes.

```
helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            showPopUpButton.setText(getInput.getText());
        }
    });
```

Since you've already defined both `showPopUpBox` and `getInput` and you've also already found them both using `findViewById` then you don't need to do it again.

Comment: Hi, I apprciate your advice however it didnt work. The above answer is correct. Thank you

Comment: That is the exact same thing that I answered!

Comment: getInput = (EditText)  checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);   had to be declared as its on different xml layouts.

Comment: ah, you just didn't know where your views were... sad